# Easiest way to query data where relationship is in a pivot table?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I've two tables which are in relation by a standard pivot table.

Now, i only want to those articles which belongs to a specific category_id

I found solutions like:

```
Article::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($cat_id) { $q->where('category_id', $cat_id); })->get();
```

Is this the best and easiest way in Laravel 5 with Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - yes, this is the way, but you could create also scope for this for cleaner usage especially in case you use it multiple times.

You can add scope into `Article` model like so:

```
public function scopeHavingCategory($query, $cat_id)
{
   return $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($cat_id) { 
           $q->where('category_id', $cat_id); 
   });
}
```

and now you can use it like so:

```
Article::havingCategory($cat_id)->get();
```